# IE8 Call javascript function from variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using below code to call function.

```
 window['GetTeenovationvideo']();
```

This function is executing in all browser but not in IE8.

In IE8 i am getting below error.

> Object doesn't support property or method 'GetTeenovationvideo'

Am i doing something wrong? Or is there any alternative way to do this.

Comment: any reason you're not just doing `GetTeenovationvideo()`?

Comment: Does `GetTeenovationvideo()` or `window.GetTeenovationvideo()` work? If not, I can understand `window["GetTeenovationvideo"]()` doesn't either.

Comment: can u post your GetTeenovationvideo() code?

Comment: @sasi not sure it would help

Comment: Can you provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so that we can test?

Comment: @ThomPorter because he want's to call the function through a variable, e.g. `window[myvar]();`

Comment: What are you assigning in window['GetTeenovationvideo'].

Comment: @simon ah yes, that is the title isn't it! lol.... I wonder if perhaps it is supposed to be "GetTeenovationVideo"?

Comment: It works fine for me in IE8, see http://tinker.io/f8a82/1  , so probably you are not assigning well a function to your `window["GetTeenovationvideo"]` variable..

Comment: GetTeenovationvideo = function GetTeenovationvideo(data) {
        $.wdpluginMiChallenge.GetTeenovationvideo(data);
    }  this is the function..

Comment: if i am calling GetTeenovationvideo() from console then also i am getting error "The value of the property 'GetTeenovationvideo' is null or undefined, not a Function object" but working fine on other browsers

Comment: From your last comment I assume that `$.wdpluginMiChallenge` has not been initialized properly, thus not having the `GetTeenovationvideo` function property. So the problem in IE8 does not lie in your call but the plugin. To test this, rename your function to something other than "GetTeenovationvideo" and call `window['yourfunction']()`

Comment: have you tried eval(window['GetTeenovationvideo'])();

Comment: Ouch! [don't use eval](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea)!